# Best way to test static function checking whether it is the first monday of the month or not (Typescript/Angular/Jasmin)

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have the following function to check whether it is the first monday of the month or not.
The function is in a static class `Validation.ts`

```
public static isFirstMondayOfMonth(): boolean {
  const d = new Date();
  const currentMonth = d.getMonth();

  // if it is monday
  if (d.getDay() === 1) {
    // Then check if we are still in the same month if we go 7 days back in time. If we're not, then it is the first monday
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
    if (currentMonth !== d.getMonth()) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

How would I test that this function works as expected? Right now my test case will only pass if it actually is the first Monday of the month. What would be a better way to test this?

```
it('Should be true if first monday of the month',() => {
  expect(Validations.isFirstMondayOfMonth()).toBeTruthy();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A deterministic function always returns the same results if given the
>   same input values. A non-deterministic function may return different
>   results every time it is called, even when the same input values are
>   provided.

`isFirstMondayOfMonth()` is a non-deterministic function. It may produce different results depending on the day it is called. Hence, it is not unit testable as it is.

I suggest converting it to a deterministic function (also called [pure function](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/benefits-of-pure-functions/)) as follows;

```
public static isFirstMondayOfMonth(date: Date): boolean {
  const d = new Date(date.getTime()); // clone the input argument for immutability
  const currentMonth = d.getMonth();

  // if it is monday
  if (d.getDay() === 1) {
    // Then check if we are still in the same month if we go 7 days back in time. If we're not, then it is the first monday
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
    if (currentMonth !== d.getMonth()) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

then test accordingly;

```js
it('Should be true if first monday of the month',() => {
  const d1 = new Date(2020, 4, 4); // first monday of May, 2020
  expect(Validations.isFirstMondayOfMonth(d1)).toBeTruthy();

  const d2 = new Date(2020, 4, 11); // second monday of May, 2020
  expect(Validations.isFirstMondayOfMonth(d2)).toBeFalsy();
})
```

Comment: Follow up question: If in production I always want to pass the current date to the function, and in testing I want to pass my own date, how can I achieve this? Hope I am making sense.

Comment: in production, where you need to check if today is the first monday of month, just pass current date as parameter to the function i.e. `Validations.isFirstMondayOfMonth(new Date())`